# Node.js: Create one global SOAP client or one client per request

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I am using NodeJS and need to connect to a SOAP service. From research, it sounds like https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap is the best package for this, though the question I have is independent of the package.

When creating a SOAP client. Should I be creating one client per APPLICATION or one client per REQUEST?

For example, say I have an endpoint `/api/someMethod` that needs to access the SOAP endpoint, should I:

a) Create the global soap client upon starting up the server and giving each route access to it

OR

b) Create a new soap client everytime the endpoint is accessed

Thanks!

Comment: I am new to Node.js. Can you please let me know how to create global client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to create one global soap client because `node-soap` isn't really async and can cause performance problems.

Full answer provided here:
https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/653